# I am trying to create a secure way to make specific users admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, admin

I have a functioning rails app with devise Admins and Users, and I want to create a secure way that will only allow users with specific IDs to become authorized to become admins. Currently, I have a static link that is not very secure that will make the current user an admin(website.com/make_admin), but I want to find the most secure method to turn specific users into administrators (I am open to all options that could accomplish this). What would be the best way for me to do this?

Comment: what kind of specific IDs are you talking about? is it emails or primary key from the user's model

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding an admin field to the user form to select if they're an admin user, but do a check in the update/create actions on your users controller to check if the current_user (if using Devise) is another admin user (or whatever role type they need to be to update other admin permissions).

You would also probably want to do a check to make sure they can't set themselves as admin=false, otherwise you could end up with no admin users left on the site and no-one with permission to change this. That said, depending on the app you could always just manually manage admin users - my company will do this depending on the client and their needs.

Comment: How/where do I manually manage who is an admin user and who isn't?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear - we do this by using the rails console to update the user. It doesn't allow anyone to do it from the actual website, but in the cases where we do it this way this doesn't matter. We create the admin user accounts that they need and then that's that, they don't need to edit any others

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) to give roles to the user's and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for access control.

You can assign roles to user either from rails console or you can generate a view for it, and restrict it to admin and assign roles to each individual user.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an admin boolean to your user model, and update it through the rails console

```
rails g migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```